# Convert bytes to Megabytes or Gigabytes for data coming from command

Tags: networking, server, bash, scripts

I have the following command:

```
cat /proc/net/dev | tr -d ':,|' | awk 'NR >= 2 {print $1 " " $2 " " $10}'
```

This lists the following output:

> face bytes packets
> docker0 2341 387821
> lo 208740 208740
> enp2s0 53877345926 60003420684

The data above is shown in bytes, I want the output to be in KB, MB or GB depending on the digits.

For example,

> face bytes packets
> docker0 18.73 KB 3.10 MB
> lo 1.67 MB 1.67 MB
> enp2s0 431.02 GB 480.03 GB

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`numfmt` is doing the bulk of the lifting below. You can tell it the format you want and additionally here I'm telling it to skip the first line, and focus on the second and third fields.

```
tail -n +2 /proc/net/dev \
| tr -d ':,|' \
| awk '{print $1 " " $2 " " $10}' \
| numfmt --to=iec --header=1 --field=2,3
```

If you want to get very much more complicated than that, or if you need this to perform better, I'd be looking to a real programming language.  They all have available libraries (or built in functions) for doing this sort of stuff and they'll do it much faster.